# Memoir, showframe and curve2e don't work well together

Tags: memoir, showframe

It seems that a combination of the `memoir` class and the `showframe` and `curve2e` packages don't work well together. Below is an MWE that I used for testing.

```
% memframeprob.tex

%\documentclass{book}
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{comment}

%\begin{comment}
\setlrmarginsandblock{0.5in}{*}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{0.5in}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{url}
%\end{comment]

\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{curve2e} % problem 


%\begin{comment}
\newcommand*{\X}{{\LARGE\textbf{.}}}
\renewcommand*{\X}{\makebox(0,0){{\large\textbf{+}}}}
\newcommand*{\Flag}{{\LARGE$\uparrow$}}
\newcommand*{\mk}{\makebox(0,0){$\circ$}}
\newcommand*{\Mk}{\makebox(0,0){$\bullet$}}
%\end{comment}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

As you can see I have tried, by commenting out bits of code, to veer in on where the problem is. When I compiled the MWE I got

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/context/base/mkii/sypp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   \bgroup
l.31 \end{document}
```

This did not occur when I used the `book` class (removing all the `memoir` specific commands) and did not occur with either `memoir` of `book` when I didn't use the `curve2e` package.

I have no idea what might be causing the problem.

Comment: This is a change in latex which curve2e wasn't expecting, give me a bit of time will post a patch later (it is reproducible using book, without memoir) this fails \documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{curve2e} % problem
\begin{document}
blub
\end{document}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the 2020-10-01 release latex picture mode allows lengths in `\put` coordinates (a feature previously but differently provided by the `picture` package).

Curve2e has been updated but misses some cases, including `\line`

```
% memframeprob.tex

%\documentclass{book}
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{comment}

%\begin{comment}
\setlrmarginsandblock{0.5in}{*}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{0.5in}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{url}
%\end{comment]

\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{curve2e} % problem 

\makeatletter



\def\line(#1)#2{\begingroup
  \@defaultunitsset\@linelen{#2}\unitlength
  \ifdim\@linelen<\z@\@badlinearg\else
    \expandafter\DirOfVect#1to\Dir@line
    \GetCoord(\Dir@line)\d@mX\d@mY
    \ifdim\d@mX\p@=\z@\else
      \edef\sc@lelen{\fpeval{1 / abs(\d@mX)}}\relax
      \@linelen=\sc@lelen\@linelen
    \fi
    \moveto(0,0)\pIIe@lineto{\d@mX\@linelen}{\d@mY\@linelen}%
    \strokepath
  \fi
\endgroup\ignorespaces}%


\makeatother


%\begin{comment}
\newcommand*{\X}{{\LARGE\textbf{.}}}
\renewcommand*{\X}{\makebox(0,0){{\large\textbf{+}}}}
\newcommand*{\Flag}{{\LARGE$\uparrow$}}
\newcommand*{\mk}{\makebox(0,0){$\circ$}}
\newcommand*{\Mk}{\makebox(0,0){$\bullet$}}
%\end{comment}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I haven't a clue about the code you provided but please don't try and explain it to me. Will `curve2e` get updated?

Comment: @PeterWilson I mailed the author, so I guess so.